# Solr Cloud Config not uploading

Tags: curl, solr, retrieve-and-rank

I'm running curl. I'm not getting an error.

```
curl -X POST -u "username":"pwd" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/scc2c46f2f_a84c_42d7_8857_a9999704dde4/config/Kbase" --data-binary @solr_config.zip
```

However, when I add a collection I get the message that it has no configuration

When I search all configs, it doesn't show.

```
curl -u "username":"pwd" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/scc2c46f2f_a84c_42d7_8857_a9999704dde4/config"
```

Comment: I just deleted out the service and tested from scratch, it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have:
-H "Content-Type: application/zip"

This is the statement:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/zip" -u "{username}":"{password}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/sc1ca23733_faa8_49ce_b3b6_dc3e193264c6/config/example_config" --data-binary @/configs/example_config.zip

I just typed it out wrong.